# Ant task for linker option --start-group and --end-group?

Tags: gcc, ant, linker

Is there a Ant task for linker option --start-group and --end-group?

'linkerarg' task cannot be placed to where I want, so it's not usable. (location option is not enough.)

I wish 'libset' task had 'group' option, but it does not.